# Already have Java REST server, which Java web framework to use?

Tags: java, web-frameworks

I already have back-end Java server that exposes interface through a REST services, sending JSON objects. I need to choose Java web framework to create front end. The only requirement is that I need charts to be supported. What would you recommend?

Thanx a lot

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084169/choosing-a-java-web-framework-now

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) for the web framework and [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) for chart drawing support.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting of charts has more to do with a client library than with a server framework. See for example [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/), which can very easily load data from a REST api.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SmartGWT](http://www.smartclient.com/product/) (see [showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#main))

** **Edit** **

I thought I remembered chart classes with SmartGWT. Anyhow, there are plenty [plugin libraries](http://uptick.com.au/content/smartgwt-and-fusioncharts) for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java development skills then GWT is a no-brainer: it's a gift in terms of client-side web development for Java developers.  I'd recommend going for GWT itself rather than a GWT wrapper on another client-side framework.  GWT seems to be the 'thinnest' wrapper that offers the smallest client-side download.  Some of them do get very large.  Plus, you're also operating 'close-to-the-metal', which can offer eased maintenance/configuration.

There are several GWT charting libraries available - so you can choose whether to use Google charts or use another open source library.